# Why does the line "subsets.push_back(n);" give me an error in the following code?

Tags: c++

I want to find the power set of a set of numbers and there is some issue I can't figure out with the code. What changes should I make??

```
vector<vector <int>> subsets={{}};
for(int i=0; i<a.size();i++){
    int elem = a[i];
    for(int j=0;j<subsets.size();j++){
        vector<int> prev = subsets[j];
        vector<int> n = prev;
        n.push_back(elem);
        subsets.push_back(n);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error :
""terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'""

Comment: infinite loop, you are calling `subsets.push_back` inside loop, so `subsets.size` is increased at every iteration of loop and it cannot be stopped, until exception is called due to lack of memory.

Comment: You could have figured out that this is an infinite loop by running the program in a debugger and examining `subsets` at the time of the crash. Alternatively, run through from the beginning for a small test case and see where it differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130209/why-does-the-line-subsets-push-backn-give-me-an-error-in-the-following-code#comment98891533_56130209):

> [You code contains an] **infinite loop**. You are calling
>   `subsets.push_back` inside loop, so `subsets.size` is increased at
>   every iteration of loop and it cannot be stopped, until exception is
>   called due to lack of memory.

Exception `std::bad_alloc` is thrown because the process is trying to allocate a *too large* memory block (as deemed by the OS) - there are ways around this but this is not the issue here, the issue is the infinite loop as already pointed out.

To avoid that particular issue you could use a range-based for loop instead (and *avoid the `push_back` within the loop*), such as:

```
for(vector<int> prev : subsets){
  //do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Using a range loop will cause undefined behaviour. Don't modify a vector that you're iterating over.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the loop condition is evaluated in its entirety on each iteration.

You're expanding `subsets` inside the loop, so `j` will always be less than `subsets.size()`.
This means that the loop will never terminate - at least not until you run out of memory or encounter some other "external" problem.

Save the limit before the loop instead:

```
const int limit = subsets.size();
for(int j = 0; j < limit; j++){
//...
```